# psycopg2: formatting data values in execute_values

Tags: python, sql, database, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm trying to insert multiple rows into my PostgreSQL table using the `execute_many` function in `psycopg2`. I can get it to work with simple values, I can't get it work with more complex data.

The following illustrates what I'm trying to do:

```
dataset = [[1,'2020-11-01 00:00:00', 1],[2,'localtimestamp', None],[3, '2020-11-01 00:00:00', '(select otherid from myothertable where otherid = 99)']]
queryText = "insert into mytable (id,timestamp,fk_id) values %s"
execute_values(cursor,querytext,dataset,template=None)
```

As you can see I'm trying to populate a field using the `localtimestamp` function, and another field with an ID from an FKed table using an embedded `select`.

When the insert query is created in the `execute_many` function the `localtimestamp` and embedded select are wrapped in quotes, which is fair enough as they are strings.  So my question is, is there a way of telling `execute_values` not to enclose a data value in quotes?

I can bypass the need to use `localtimestamp` relatively easily by populating `dataset` with an ISO date string, but getting the embedded query working is more complicated.  I'm trying not to build the query myself and just using `conn.execute(...)` as for obvious reasons, that's not a safe approach.

Any suggestions gratefully received.  Thanks

Comment: You are trying to mix values with SQL, and that is a really bad idea.  Your code does not work because psycopg2 guards against SQL injection.

Comment: As @MikeOrganek said that is not going to work as `execute_values` is expecting just that values not a query. Not  sure why you think `conn.execute()` is not safe?

Comment: Yup, unfortunately that's exactly what I'm trying to do. I'm aware of the possibility of SQL injection and account for that in the code.  But thanks for your reply.  So, basically for very good reasons, psycopg2 wont let me do what I want to do.  I'll have handle this differently. Cheers.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver: "not safe" as in open to SQL injection if I don't ensure the SQL is clean, and I was hoping I could reply on psycopg2 to help me with that. But it looks like I'm going to have to build my onw SQL and use `conn.execute()` (which I was doing first anyway, I just thought there was a more elegant solution)

Comment: `execute()` will accept [parameters](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries). There is also the [sql](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/sql.html) module to help build dynamic queries safely. If you are the one building the queries then I don't see a problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [AsIs](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extensions.html?highlight=asis#psycopg2.extensions.AsIs), to prevent your subqueries get quoted:

```
dataset = [[1,'2020-11-01 00:00:00', 1],[2,'2020-11-01 00:00:00', None],[3, '2020-11-01 00:00:00', "(select id from __users where lastname = 'Reinisch')"]]

for i, data in enumerate(dataset):
    if isinstance(data[2], str):
        data[2] = AsIs(data[2])
    # same here for the functions

queryText = "insert into mytable (id,ts,fk_id) values %s"
execute_values(cursor,queryText,dataset,template=None)

cursor.execute('select * from mytable')
pprint.pprint(cursor.fetchall())
```

Out:

```
[(1, datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 1, 0, 0), 1),
 (2, datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 1, 0, 0), None),
 (3, datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 1, 0, 0), 366211)]
```

**Note**:

I didn't check for postgres functions, but should work the same or something like `SELECT localtimestamp()`, but as mentioned it is not save!

Comment: I would be careful of this for the reasons Daniele Varrazzo(piro) mentions in this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42980069/7070613)